# Youtube push notifications

Tags: youtube-api, push-notification

I came across this video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlZZghBnfdM

Yet I can't find anything in the api docs to suggest how to do this or if it's even available yet.

Does anyone have any information on youtube push notifications? I'm hoping it'll be available for a server to server implementation.

Regards,
Mat

Answer (score 3):

There are channel Push notifications in https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications

Comment: Where is it? It had been 4+ months.